# twisted.web.server.Session - alternative Session class/factory that can refresh the timeout

Tags: session, web, twisted

The stock Session factory for twisted.web.server.Session has the property `sessionTimeout` set to 900 seconds (I believe 15 minutes).

Since Session remains stored in memory as part of twisted.web.server.Site HTTPFactory it does make sense to have house keeping logic.  Except as I understand `Session`'s time out, it starts ticking down from 900 seconds the moment it is created and will never be refreshed or duplicated.

It feels trivial to reimplement session with something like the TimeoutMixin used on twisted.web `class Request` but before I do so I wanted to sanity check I am not missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how I missed this but `twisted.web.server.Session` has a `touch` method which resets the expiration timer.   The source code is here https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/src/twisted/web/server.py#L768